# Gerar um JSON a partir de um XML convertido com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml

Consegui efetuar uma conversão de um xml pra json utilizando uma solução que encontrei na internet e me atendeu perfeitamente, ele armazena todo o json em uma string e mostra na tela, porém não sei como faço pra jogar o conteudo dessa string em um arquivo.json

Segue o código da minha index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Gerar Json</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xml2json.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <pre id="jsnstr"></pre>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jsonstr = xml2json.fromFile('arquivo.xml', 'string');
        document.getElementById('jsnstr').innerHTML = jsonstr;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Código do javascript que converte o xml para json:

```js
// Converts XML to JSON
// from: http://coursesweb.net/javascript/convert-xml-json-javascript_s2
function XMLtoJSON() {
    var me = this; // stores the object instantce

    // gets the content of an xml file and returns it in 
    me.fromFile = function(xml, rstr) {
        // Cretes a instantce of XMLHttpRequest object
        var xhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        // sets and sends the request for calling "xml"
        xhttp.open("GET", xml, false);
        xhttp.send(null);

        // gets the JSON string
        var json_str = jsontoStr(setJsonObj(xhttp.responseXML));

        // sets and returns the JSON object, if "rstr" undefined (not passed), else, returns JSON string
        return (typeof(rstr) == 'undefined') ? JSON.parse(json_str) : json_str;
    }

    // returns XML DOM from string with xml content
    me.fromStr = function(xml, rstr) {
        // for non IE browsers
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            var getxml = new DOMParser();
            var xmlDoc = getxml.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        } else {
            // for Internet Explorer
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = "false";
        }

        // gets the JSON string
        var json_str = jsontoStr(setJsonObj(xmlDoc));

        // sets and returns the JSON object, if "rstr" undefined (not passed), else, returns JSON string
        return (typeof(rstr) == 'undefined') ? JSON.parse(json_str) : json_str;
    }

    // receives XML DOM object, returns converted JSON object
    var setJsonObj = function(xml) {
        var js_obj = {};
        if (xml.nodeType == 1) {
            if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
                js_obj["@attributes"] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                    var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                    js_obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.value;
                }
            }
        } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) {
            js_obj = xml.nodeValue;
        }
        if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
                var nodeName = item.nodeName;
                if (typeof(js_obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                    js_obj[nodeName] = setJsonObj(item);
                } else {
                    if (typeof(js_obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                        var old = js_obj[nodeName];
                        js_obj[nodeName] = [];
                        js_obj[nodeName].push(old);
                    }
                    js_obj[nodeName].push(setJsonObj(item));
                }
            }
        }
        return js_obj;
    }

    // converts JSON object to string (human readablle).
    // Removes '\t\r\n', rows with multiples '""', multiple empty rows, '  "",', and "  ",; replace empty [] with ""
    var jsontoStr = function(js_obj) {
        var rejsn = JSON.stringify(js_obj, undefined, 2).replace(/(\\t|\\r|\\n)/g, '').replace(/"",[\n\t\r\s]+""[,]*/g, '').replace(/(\n[\t\s\r]*\n)/g, '').replace(/[\s\t]{2,}""[,]{0,1}/g, '').replace(/"[\s\t]{1,}"[,]{0,1}/g, '').replace(/\[[\t\s]*\]/g, '""');
        return (rejsn.indexOf('"parsererror": {') == -1) ? rejsn : 'Invalid XML format';
    }
};

// creates object instantce of XMLtoJSON
var xml2json = new XMLtoJSON();
```

XML exemplo:

```html
<a>
    <child id='MNU1' />
    <child id='MNU2'/>
    <child id='MNU3'/>
    <child id='MNU4'/>
    <child id='MNU5'/>
    <child id='MNU6'/>
    <child id='MNU7'/>
    <child id='MNU8'/>
</a>
```

Estou com esse problema no momento e não encontrei nenhuma solução até agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "jogar o conteudo dessa string em um arquivo.json"

Você **não** consegue salvar pois o script esta rodando no cliente, por questoes de segurança você não tem acesso a salvar automaticamente arquivos nele.

Você tem algumas opções para salvar dados no browser:

### LocalStorage

Você pode armazenar dados na máquina do cliente como este:

```
var data = { name: 'Bob', age: 12 };
Window.localStorage.setItem('person', data);
```

Em seguida, em uma página diferente no mesmo domínio, você pode então recuperar esses dados:

```
var data = Window.localStorage.getItem('person');
```

Porém, note que algumas configurações de segurança do navegador desativam o localStorage para que ele não funcione em todas as situações.

Mais uma leitura aqui:

[Using_the_Web_Storage_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)

### Cookies

A outra alternativa é usar cookies .

```
document.cookie = "name=Bob";
document.cookie = "age=12";
console.log(document.cookie); // displays: name=Bob;age=12
```

Mais uma leitura aqui:

[cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

--

Você também consegue fazer é gerar um arquivo e solicitar "salvar como" ao usuário.

Pode usar a lib [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

[Exemplo](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223192500/https://codepen.io/davidelrizzo/pen/cxsGb)

Comment: Puts, não havia pensado nisso hehe.  
Será que então tenho que usar um php por exemplo para que seja gerado o arquivo que desejo a partir daquela variável ?

Comment: @WesleyBrito. Entao, vai depender da sua necessidade, pra que você quer este JSON?

Comment: basicamente eu vou ler esse Json para gerar algumas telas em angular com o conteudo desse json, pensando em uma forma mais grosseira me surgiu esse questionamento de criar arquivos json a partir de alguns xmls.

Comment: Quer salvar este JSON no servidor?

Comment: sim, por enquanto está em desenvolvimento local mas ele vai ficar provavelmente em um  node server.

Comment: Vai ter que salvar esse arquivo com linguagem Server-side mesmo. um PHP resolve seu problema :)

Comment: ok, valeu o auxílio.

Answer (score 0):

**Eu encontrei um código online que acho que pode ajudar:**

```
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

**E depois converte assim:**

```
var jsonConverted = JSON.stringify(xmlToJson(xmlDoc));
```

Para mais informações clique [AQUI](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json)

Comment: pedro esse código que voce me enviou ele apenas já faz oque eu já tenho, meu código já gera um json eu quero colocar o conteudo da string que está armazenando o json dentro de um arquivo.json.

Comment: voce pode usar a libraria `fs` para escrever um ficheiro json
http://jsbin.com/rizifasaji/edit?js,console

Comment: onde encontra essa biblioteca ?